# $x(A)=\cup_{y} x\left(A \cap W_{y}\right)$ where $y: W_{y} \rightarrow M $, what does the $\cup_{y}$ mean?

Tags: differential-geometry, notation

I am having difficulty understanding the notation for a homework problem (which is given directly as handout). I will reproduce the statement for the part of the question here.

> $
> \begin{array}{l}{\text { Let } M \text { be a regular surface. Deduce that if } x: U \rightarrow M \subset \mathbb{R}^{3} \text { is a regular chart }} \\ {\text { (possibly without a continuous inverse), then } x(A) \text { is open in } M \text { for every open }} \\ {\text { set } A \subset U . \text { Hint: decompose } x(A)=\cup_{y} x\left(A \cap W_{y}\right) \text { where } y: W_{y} \rightarrow M \text { is a }} \\ {\text { regular chart with continuous inverse. }}\end{array}
> $

I just do not understand what $\cup_{y}$ denotes (I would normally expect a union symbol to be subscripted over some index), it seems to me like extending the original function, but what exactly is it?

Comment: You know, you can always ask your instructor. I promise they won't bite.

Comment: Yeah and also my friends... The problem is that at the time of the posting of this question, it was already 10PM the day before it was due. I really wished that I had started the assignment earlier.

Comment: LOL. Well, I can't say I haven't thought the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is an indexed union, as you suspect. The hint is asking you to provide a family of regular charts $\{y_i : W_i \to M_i \subseteq M\}_{i \in I}$, each with a continuous inverse, such that $\bigcup_{i \in I} W_i = U$. Then $x(A) = \bigcup_{i \in I} x(A \cap W_i)$. The notation is perhaps a bit confusing but I don't what else the hint could mean.